# Nginx + FPM PHP: where the uploaded files are sent? And tmp dir security

Tags: security, nginx, upload, php, tmp

I need to know where the uploaded files are sent when a user upload a file like an image through php.
The files are writen direct to de destination directory in scripts or they uploaded to an tmp dir? In this case, would be nice if tmp dir were mounted with flags noexec and nosuid. With FPM PHP and NGINX, this is necessary?

Thank you.

Comment: The question where to find, [see](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir)

Comment: when I list the content of the directory /tmp while I upload an file, the dir is showing empty. PS: the script is run as user that owner directory.

Comment: i'm using Debian 7 with Nginx + FPM PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [NGINX + PHP-FPM tmp dir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271496/nginx-php-fpm-tmp-dir)

Answer (score 0):

I change the var tmp_upload_dir and when a file is uploaded, the directory still empty.