# NGINX + PHP-FPM tmp dir

Tags: nginx, php, tmp

I need to know where the uploaded files are sent when a user upload a file like an image through php. The files are written direct to the destination directory in scripts or they uploaded to an tmp directory? In this case, would be nice if tmp directory were mounted with flags `noexec` and `nosuid`. With FPM PHP and NGINX, this is necessary? when I list the content of the directory `/tmp` while I upload an file, the directory is showing empty.

PS: the script is running as user that owner directory. I change the var `tmp_upload_di`r and when a file is uploaded, the directory still empty.

Comment: Did you verify that when you changed the tmp_upload_dir that it was changed for that specific FPM connection? Run a phpinfo to see on that specific domain to make sure.

Comment: Yes, on phpinfo, the value in Local Value and Master Value of tmp_upload_dir is the value defined in config file, but when I uploading very large or small files, the directory used as tmp is empty.

Comment: The files are uploaded to tmp dir then moved to other dir or uploaded direct to the destination directory?